# Control the font size of Text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Widgets become messy after changing the device font setting to the largest. Any trick to control this behaviour so that I can change the device font settings, but widgets don't get messy?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your widgets size with the help of textScale factor. The default value is 1.0.

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
```

Use this in you widgets to adjust some overflowing widgets you might have.